# Limit of a test function times exp

Tags: calculus, distribution-theory

So while working on some calculus for distributions I came across the following integral:

$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^+} exp(\lambda x) \varphi dx
$

Where $\varphi$ is a test function of compact support. To evaluate such an integral i first thought about doing an integration by parts. But while doing this I came up with the limit:

$lim_{x \rightarrow\infty} exp(\lambda x)\varphi$

Which at first glance seems to be indeterminate, is there any way to justify this limit existing or maybe another approach to make this calcuulation?

Comment: Since the test function has compact support, the limit is $0$

Comment: I get that, but still the limit would be of the form $\infty . 0$,  which is still undetermined

Comment: That's not how compact support works at all. There exists an $M$ such that for all $|x|>M$ the test function is *identically* zero, not *approaching* zero.